# Lazyloading rowcount error for Primefaces datatable using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement lazy loading for my JSF datatable, my application is using JSF2.0. Spring 3 and Hibernate 4.

I have the following in DAO

```
@Override
public int getRequestCount() {          
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Request.count");
    return ((Long) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

and in ManagedBean I have

```
@Named("reqMB")
@Scope("request")
public class RequestManagedBean implements Serializable {

// other code .....    
lazyModel.setRowCount(getRequestService().getRequestCount());
....
return lazyModel;
```

in Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_REQUESTS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.count", query = "SELECT COUNT(r) FROM <viewname> r")
})
public class Request {
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to deploy my application to weblogic 10.3.6, I am getting the following exception.

```
Error creating bean with name 'requestDAOImpl': Injection of 
autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory 
net.test.request.dao.RequestDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Errors in named queries: Request.count
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Another point is instead of using the following, are there any other ways of getting rowcount for lazyloading?

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Request.count", query = "SELECT COUNT(r) 
    FROM vw_request r")})
```

Thanks

Comment: SELECT COUNT(r) FROM <viewname> r; <viewname> is a place holder because you somehow want to hide the true name of the view? Or is that -really- the query you're firing.

Comment: @Gimby That is only the placeholder, actual name is `vw_request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue, mistake I made was
instead of Class name I have used actual view name, so I changed to

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Request.count", query = "SELECT COUNT(r) FROM Request r").
```

My other doubt was without using the above to get the rowcount, I have modified my DAO as follows, with this I do not need to have @NamedQuery in Entity class.

```
int count = ((Long)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(*) 
from Request").uniqueResult()).intValue();
```